# Reference reassignment in C++ Primer

Tags: c++, reference

In C++ Primer 5th Edition, there is a section on references and `const`, in pages 97-98:

```
const int temp = dval;   // create a temporary const int from the double
const int &ri = temp;    // bind ri to that temporary
```

> In this case, ri is bound to a temporary object. A temporary object is an unnamed
>   object created by the compiler when it needs a place to store a result from evaluating
>   an expression. C++ programmers often use the word temporary as an abbreviation
>   for temporary object.
>   Now consider what could happen if this initialization were allowed but ri was not
>   const. If ri weren’t const, we could assign to ri. Doing so would change the
>   object to which ri is bound.

I may be wrong, but I thought that references *cannot* be "re-seated" or "re-bound". My problem is with the last sentence:

**If ri weren’t const, we could assign to ri. Doing so would change the
object to which ri is bound.**

Is this a mistake in the book, or am I misunderstanding something here?

From my understanding, a reference can be thought of an *alias* or alternative name for a variable, although I am not entirely sure if this is correct.

Thank you for your time

Comment: The language is vague. It simply means to say "if `ri` was not const, an assignment to `ri` would assign to `temp`, but since it's a const reference, that assignment isn't possible at all". Nothing about re-binding the reference at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doing so would change the object to which ri is bound.

This sentence is a bit ambiguous. You're reading it as "*Doing so would change which object ri is bound to*", but that's not what the author meant. It's supposed to be read as

> Doing so would make changes to an object (namely the one ri is bound to).

---

> From my understanding, a reference can be thought of an *alias* or alternative name for a variable

That's exactly right. For example:

```
int i = 0;
int &r = i;
r = 42;
```

Here `r` is an alias for `i`, so the assignment to `r` in the last line changes (i.e. sets to `42`) the object that `r` is bound to (which is `i`). In other words, it sets `i` to `42`.